# Roll up: typescript error (!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

I am having issues with rollup

> this has been rewritten to undefined

during rollup. Please someone should help me out on this.

I found a hint online "you can use `options.context` and `options.moduleContext` to change this behaviour. I also don't know how to implement this.

Please enlighten me in anyway you can.

After running the below command

```
"build": "rollup -c",
"build-watch": "rollup -c -w",
```

it was suppose to pick up, watch and run files successfully.

Comment: It looks like the Rollup docs explain both options; `context` can be used to set `this = this` if that's the correct context, and `moduleContext` does it per-module. I might be *more* inclined to see if the underlying issue can be fixed, but no information is provided regarding what's actually *causing* the issue, though.